# Unable to activate sinatra-contrib gem

Tags: rubygems, sinatra, rvm, bundler

When I run `ruby application.rb` in my [Sinatra forked](https://github.com/juanpastas/sinatra) app, I'm having in console:

```
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1637:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate sinatra-contrib-1.3.1, because sinatra-1.4.0 conflicts with sinatra (~> 1.3.0) (Gem::LoadError)
```

See that:

```
bundle show sinatra
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bundler/gems/sinatra-b18310f73635
```

and

```
# Gemfile
source :rubygems
gem 'sinatra', git: 'https://github.com/juanpastas/sinatra.git'
```

and

```
bundle exec ruby application.rb 
application.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- sinatra/content_for (LoadError)
```

if I add `gem 'sinatra-contrib'` to Gemfile, and the run `bundle`, I get:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sinatra":
  In Gemfile:
    sinatra-contrib (>= 0) ruby depends on
      sinatra (~> 1.3.0) ruby

    sinatra (1.4.0)
```

Comment: have you tried adding `gem 'sinatra'` before the `require` ?

Comment: I've tried it but nothing. Byt the way, $LOAD_PATH contains `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bundler/gems/sinatra-b18310f73635/lib`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using old version of `sinatra-contrib`, switch to git version:

```
source :rubygems
gem 'sinatra', git: 'https://github.com/juanpastas/sinatra.git'
gem 'sinatra-contrib', git: 'https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra-contrib.git'
```

Comment: I thought `~>` meant any version `greater than 1.3`, and it means `greater or equal to 1.3 and less than 1.4`([bundler help](http://gembundler.com/rationale.html)). Thanks for helping me.